# Ruby On Rails : DOcker : Is it feasible to build ROR project dependencies inside docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ubuntu, docker

I work on a project built on ROR. This projects has dependent gems and packages such as `Fog`, `rmagick`, `sidekiq`, `elasticsearch`, `carrierwave`, `imagemagic`, `engineyard`, `ruby`, `rails`, etc.

**Problems we faced:**
Frequently laptops of my fellow developers crash. It takes the whole working-day to install all the dependent gems and packages in linux `Ubuntu 14.04 / 15.04`.

- Is it possible to build everything I mentioned above inside a docker image and distribute among the developers?
- Can we run rails like `rails s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to build everything I mentioned above inside a docker image and distribute among the developers?

Yes! I'm running a couple of Rails applications in Docker containers. Apart from Mark O'Connor's link I suggest you check out:

> This is a demo app I created show how to develop and deploy a moderately complex application with docker.

1. https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-rails-dev-demo

Or (more advanced)

2. https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker

These are examples of how you can build a Rails image. *As far as distributing goes:* You'll probably have to setup your own [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) or in case you don't mind having the images in out in the open push it to the docker.io registry.

> Can we run rails like rails s?

Yes you can think of a docker container as an execution environment for your rails application. All your typical commands can be run.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out the official rails image from Docker

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rails/

This will still download dependencies but you could adapt it to build a base container that already includes the dependencies.